# fatal error encountered during command execution in c#.net mysql

Tags: c#

I have tried the code below when I am going to click Save button I got the error of "fatal error encountered during command execution" I rechecked more than two times but unfortunately error not go away. please, anyone kindly fix this error.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cid, lname, fname,street,city,state,phone,date,email,aco,actype,des,bal;

            cid = label14.Text;
            lname = textBox1.Text;
            fname = textBox2.Text;
            street = textBox3.Text;
            city = textBox4.Text;
            state = textBox5.Text;
            phone = textBox6.Text;
            date = dateTimePicker1.Text;
            email = textBox8.Text;


            aco = textBox7.Text;
            actype = comboBox1.Text;
            des = textBox10.Text;
            bal = textBox11.Text;

            con.Open();


            MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            MySqlTransaction transaction;

            transaction = con.BeginTransaction();

            StringBuilder cmdText = new StringBuilder();
          cmdText.AppendLine("INSERT into customer (custid,lastname,firstname,street,city,state,phone,date,email) VALUES (@custid,@lastname,@firstname,@street,@city,@state,@phone,@date,@email)");
           cmdText.AppendLine("INSERT into account(accid,custid,acctype,description,balance) VALUES (@accid,@custoid,@acctype,@description,@balance)");



            cmd.CommandText = cmdText.ToString();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Transaction = transaction;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custid", cid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", fname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@street", street);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", state);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phone);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accid", aco);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cusotid", cid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acctype", actype);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", des);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", bal);







            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();



                transaction.Commit();
                MessageBox.Show("Transaction Suceess");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Instead of MessageBox.Show(ex.Message) MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()) or debug it and share the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen many developers encountering errors with their SQL because they are using `AddWithValue` on their `SqlCommand`. The issue with this is that the command doesn't know the data type of your sql command parameter.

You should use [SqlParameterCollection.Add Method (String, SqlDbType, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40959t6x(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the data type of the parameter. Refer to [SqlDbType Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `SqlDbType` enumeration.

Usage:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@custid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cid;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.Text).Value = lname;
```

P.S. I am assuming that there are no issues with your SQL connection string.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custid", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = cid;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = lname;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname",MySqlDbType.Text).Value =  fname;
     but agian i got 1 error input string was not it current format

Comment: @PrabigaDuraisamy try `SqlDbType.String` on your `@custid`. I also suggest using separate `SqlCommands` for inserting to `customer` and `account` table.

Comment: @PrabigaDuraisamy can you check your parameter names? I noticed that in your insert statement you use `@custoid` but you are setting `cusotid` in your parameters. Keep those sql commands separated, it's for the better.